# What's with these cats' eyes?

Tags: cats, health, diseases, vision, eye-disease

They are siblings. Their mother has good eyes. It seems that the eyes of the other two siblings are OK; but with these two, something is wrong.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Take them to the vet asap, cats lick each other and it could be contagious

Answer (score 8):

They need to see a vet, chances are it's feline rhinotracheitis which can cause some issues with eyes (we see this a lot in our cats from the SPCA), it could also be an eye infection which would require antibiotic eye drops.

Only way to know and treat is by taking them to a vet.